# How i can navigate into php objects generated by joomla

Tags: php, object, joomla3.1

How i can navigate into php objects generated by joomla like this:

```
object(JForm)#179 (5) {
  ["data":protected]=>
  object(JRegistry)#178 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    object(stdClass)#177 (12) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["title"]=>
....
```

i want to fetch value of `id`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php and also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: so, i can not access protected methods directly. is it true?

Comment: Usually you to this usigng `OBJECT->get('VARIABLENAME')`;